# (python) How to convert a function to module in tkinter environment

Tags: python, function, tkinter, module

I tried to convert a function to a module in tkinter; however, it failed.

**Original version**: embed a function (sl_adder) in main codes

Here I use `.get()` function

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def sl_adder():
    aa = float(xxx.get())
    bb = float(yyy.get())
    cc = aa + bb
    mylabel = ttk.Label(root, text = cc).grid(column=1, row=4, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)

root = Tk()
root.title('Denny')
root.geometry("800x900")

xxx = StringVar()
yyy = StringVar()



ttk.Label(root,text = "Adding System", font=('Arial', 25)).grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+N)  
ttk.Label(root,text = "Input Two Numbers", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=5, pady=20, sticky=W+N)   
ttk.Label(root,text = "1st number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=2, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)   
ttk.Label(root,text = "2nd number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=3, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)  

ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=xxx, width=20).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N) 
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=yyy, width=20).grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)

resultButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Calculate', command = sl_adder)
resultButton.grid(column=3, row=2, pady=15, sticky=W)

close_window = ttk.Button(root, text="Destroy", command = root.destroy)
close_window.grid(column=3, row=3, pady=15, sticky=W)
```

Second version: convert a function to a module (sl_adder)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from sl_adder import sl_adder   # <-------------------------

root = Tk()
root.title('Denny')
root.geometry("800x900")

xxx = StringVar()
yyy = StringVar()



ttk.Label(root,text = "Adding System", font=('Arial', 25)).grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+N)  
ttk.Label(root,text = "Input Two Numbers", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=5, pady=20, sticky=W+N)   
ttk.Label(root,text = "1st number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=2, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)   
ttk.Label(root,text = "2nd number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=3, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)   

ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=xxx, width=20).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N) 
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=yyy, width=20).grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)

resultButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Calculate', command = sl_adder)
resultButton.grid(column=3, row=2, pady=15, sticky=W)

close_window = ttk.Button(root, text="Destroy", command = root.destroy)
close_window.grid(column=3, row=3, pady=15, sticky=W)
```

Module `sl_adder`:

```
def sl_adder():
    aa = float(xxx.get())
    bb = float(yyy.get())
    cc = aa + bb
    mylabel = ttk.Label(root, text = cc).grid(column=1, row=4, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)
```

When I ran it, it shows:

```
NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined
```

How to fix it?    I only remove the function and produce a module.

============================================================

Now I fix that as following

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from sl_adder import sl_adder

root = Tk()
root.title('Denny')
root.geometry("800x900")

xxx = StringVar()
yyy = StringVar()



ttk.Label(root,text = "Adding System", font=('Arial', 25)).grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+N)  
ttk.Label(root,text = "Input Two Numbers", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=5, pady=20, sticky=W+N)   
ttk.Label(root,text = "1st number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=2, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)   
ttk.Label(root,text = "2nd number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=3, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)   

ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=xxx, width=20).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N) 
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=yyy, width=20).grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)

aa = float(xxx.get())    # <=====================
bb = float(yyy.get())    # <=====================

resultButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Calculate', command = sl_adder(aa,bb))
resultButton.grid(column=3, row=2, pady=15, sticky=W)

close_window = ttk.Button(root, text="Destroy", command = root.destroy)
close_window.grid(column=3, row=3, pady=15, sticky=W)




root.mainloop()
```

With module

```
def sl_adder(aa,bb):
    cc = aa + bb
    mylabel = ttk.Label(root, text = cc).grid(column=1, row=4, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)
```

However, another error pops out

```
aa = float(xxx.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Main program and module are in different workspaces, so you need to pass the required items to `sl_adder()` via arguments.

Comment: @acw1668 I modified it; however, another error pops out. Not sure how to overcome it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use something like `command=lambda: sl_adder(xxx.get(), yyy.get())` instead.  But it has other issue inside `sl_adder()`: `root` is not defined.  Suggest to create the result label in main program instead of inside `sl_addr()`.  Then you need to return the result at the end of `sl_adder()` and then use `command=lambda: mylabel.config(text=sl_adder(xxx.get(), yyy.get()))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since main application and module are in different workspaces, you cannot access global variables in main application directly inside module.  However you can pass them via function arguments.

Also it is better to create the result label in main application instead of inside module function.  Main application can get the result from the module function and update the result text.

Main application:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from sl_adder import sl_adder

root = Tk()
root.title('Denny')
root.geometry("800x900")

xxx = StringVar()
yyy = StringVar()

ttk.Label(root,text = "Adding System", font=('Arial', 25)).grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+N)
ttk.Label(root,text = "Input Two Numbers", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=5, pady=20, sticky=W+N)
ttk.Label(root,text = "1st number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=2, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)
ttk.Label(root,text = "2nd number: ", font=('Arial', 10)).grid(column=0, row=3, ipadx=5, pady=15, sticky=W+N)

ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=xxx, width=20).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=yyy, width=20).grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)

resultButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Calculate',
                          # update result label with the returned result
                          command = lambda: mylabel.config(text=sl_adder(xxx.get(), yyy.get())))
resultButton.grid(column=3, row=2, pady=15, sticky=W)

close_window = ttk.Button(root, text="Destroy", command = root.destroy)
close_window.grid(column=3, row=3, pady=15, sticky=W)

# create the label for showing the result
mylabel = ttk.Label(root)
mylabel.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=N)

root.mainloop()
```

module `sl_adder`:

```py
def sl_adder(aa, bb):
    # return the result to caller
    return float(aa) + float(bb)
```